# how do i ensure a select statement returns null values for specific columns?

Tags: sql-server

This might sound kind of weird, but I have a query that joins two tables. I'm using an IF statements that dictates what to return. One path runs the query/join as is, the other needs to return all of the data from the first column, but only return column names with null values. Here's the query i have now:

```
declare @Date DATE = '06/07/2012'
IF @DATE >= GETDATE()    
    BEGIN
        SELECT DisplayName, '' [RegularHours], ''[OvertimeHours] 
        FROM Sites
        ORDER BY DisplayName
    END
    ELSE 
        SELECT sites.DisplayName, hrs.SiteDate, hrs.RegularHrs, hrs.OverTimeHrs
        FROM Sites sites
        left join SiteHours hrs on sites.SiteID = hrs.SiteID
        ORDER BY DisplayName
```

What's making me nervous is that the second and third columns do not have values at all, not even NULL. I'm worried that this will pose a problem later. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, I think you can do:

```
SELECT DisplayName, NULL as 'RegularHours', NULL as 'OvertimeHours'
```

Comment: Except I wouldn't use `'single quotes'` as column/alias delimiters - this syntax has been deprecated. You should use `[square brackets]` instead where required (e.g. columns with a space, start with a number or other non-alpha character, or reserved word/keyword). In this case, no alias delimiters are necessary.

Comment: You might want to `CAST` the NULLs so that the data types match the second query's columns.